# Splitting a monolith file Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, refactoring

First to set the scene a little. I am working on piece of software that has been worked on by a number of developers over the years, each making improvements, and compromises along the way. We have about 30 apps in the project, but about 60% of all of the code is in one models file.

In recent years we have been moving away from this monolithic architecture, but we have not had the time/willingness to actually spilt this file up. It is causing issues just loading and searching the file at the moment.

I am looking for any advice or strategies that could help with this.

I have been looking into three methods/paths, but I am not sure if they are a good idea, or if there is a better one.

1. Moving Models out 1-by-1. Hard code in the database name, and then overwrite the migration so no data is deleted, and move out each model one by one to their new home.
2. Make the file into a directory. Instead of being one file, split this up into a number of files. This will alleviate the current issues we are having with the file size. And will also spilt it all up for moving at a later date (which will definitely happen).
3. Delegate the classes to their new homes. This was a suggestion from someone, but I have not found any other examples of it in Django, only delegation of methods. But basically move a model to a new home, and point to it from the main file.

Does anyone have any advice which of these would be the best path? We're using Django3.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will relay what I read in django books. I am a beginner, so take my advice with a grain of salt.

Split the model into a directory. Whether you end up sticking with this approach or not it will be a good start to logically break this huge file into smaller pieces. From there you can decide what is better.

I have also read that there are two approaches to logic in django apps:

1. Fat models and skinny views
2. Skinny models and fat views

As the naming suggests these approaches show where most of the logic resides (in your case in your fat models). If you are determined to break down this huge models file into smaller ones it might be beneficial to consider offloading some of the logic to the views. Refactoring is time consuming so consider what is best in your particular case

Here are the articles that I've read on this topic:

https://medium.com/@jairvercosa/django-model-guideline-d48a96c9b38c

https://sunscrapers.com/blog/where-to-put-business-logic-django/